How to plot a ray intersecting a point uniformly between two rays?
I have two rays and a point. I need to dynamically plot a new ray which has an origin placed uniformly in-between that of the other two ray origins and which also intersects the point.
For instance, here are two examples:


The naming of the points in the images is poor, and generally unrelated to the problem. The rays may be treated as lines.

What is your criterion for “uniformly placed between the other two rays”? Visually it looks like you’re requiring all the rays to have a common origin.

Do you just mean the third ray should pass through the point where the other two rays meet?

"a new ray that intersects the point", that point must belong to that line, right?

@Semiclassical The new ray's origin must be in-between the two origins of the initial rays. The question that I'm trying to solve is "how far in-between?"

@MPW the third ray must pass through an existing point such as the one in my screenshots.

I would say extend the first two rays back to the right to find their point of intersection. Then the third ray would be on the line joining that point to the third point. Your "origin" would be where that ray crosses the segment between the base points of the other two rays.

I found another solution for the intercept after doing some more work. It's a good bit simpler. We treat the area behind the rays as a triangle. We have the distance between the two origins and we can also find the angles of that theoretical triangle. This turns it into an Angle-Side-Angle triangle problem. If we solve for the length of a side of that triangle, then we have the distance the intercept point is from one of the ray origins.

@MPW's commented solution is intuitive and works fantastic. Find the slope of each ray (which I treated as lines). Then, find the slope's intercept which can be used as an origin for the new ray to the hovering point.

Here's the math.
And here's the code I ended up using in the context of my problem:
// M & B are in the context of the slope formula
float firstM = firstDirection.y / firstDirection.x;
float firstB = -firstM * startPoint.x + startPoint.y;
float lastM = lastDirection.y / lastDirection.x;
float lastB = -lastM * endPoint.x + endPoint.y;
float interceptX = (lastB - firstB) / (firstM - lastM);
float interceptY = (-lastM * firstB + firstM * lastB) / (firstM - lastM);

